# MongoDB String to Double conversion during aggregation pipeline

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

In my documents, the decimal values are stored as `String` ( Because of my `BigDecimal` in Java converted to `String`). This is perfectly OK and required when I am looking one document at a time. However, I require them to be treated as `Double` during aggregation purpose (for e.g., `$sum`).

Is there a way so that I can covert the `String` to `Double` during `$project` operation (or otherwise) during my aggregation pipeline. So that my successive pipelines will do `$sum` on the `Double` field.

I am not considering the option of storing them as `Double`, as I would need to preserve the precision per document basis, but I am OKif the precision is lost during my aggregation operation.

Comment: Simply put, No. You cannot cast in the aggregation pipeline at present. The best you can do is "integer/double" ( and the later is "sort of" ) to string, and quite obscurely by using **`$substr`**. If you really need "cating" right now, then use mapReduce instead. But I don't see a use case or code here for which we can provide an answer. If you want to use the aggregation pipeline, store the data as a double. Even better, store the data as two seperate number types. Floating point math = headache.

Comment: Also -- vote [this](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-1393) issue up to add support for a decimal/currency type. I've been told in person that it's important, but I never seen any movement on the actual issue.

Comment: Related: https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-11400

Comment: Can you please check my answer? 5 years later, a simpler solution is available =)

Answer (score 3):

There is no operator to do conversions in aggregation pipeline. Is it possible to store two different values one as BigDecimal / String and another as a double / float value? That can be one of quick and dirty option if you are ok to ignore the flakiness due to the floating point values.

Comment: Yes, that is a possible option I am also considering if there is no other alternative. I am planning to make this transformation at framework level, so that the rest of code is transparent to storage method.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`$toDouble`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/toDouble/), which is essentially a short hand for [`$convert`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/convert/#exp._S_convert) with `to: "double"`

Assume we have a document;

```
{
    "str": "3.66"
}
```

and to convert the `string` value to `double`;

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $addFields: {
      double: {
        $toDouble: "$str"
      }
    }
  }
])
```

will result in;

```
{
    "str": "3.66",
    "double": 3.66
}
```

Where it can be used by other stages of aggregation pipeline.

Check on [Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/xKpOBi1LcpI)

Comment: use convert for better error handling `{$convert: { input: "$col_28769", to: "double", onError: "Error", onNull: "Null"}`

Comment: its not working when we have value with comma like "30,000.66"

Answer (score 0):

Mongodb version 4.0 introduced the `$toInt` operator in the aggregation pipeline. You can use that to convert easily from string to number.
Link to documentation: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/toInt/